# How to pass an id from template to view

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

this is my view :

```
def delete_chat(request, id):
     chat=get_object_or_404(Chat,id=id)
     chat.delete()
     return redirect('msgs:inbox')
```

and this is my template:

```
<a href="{% url 'msgs:delete_chat' id=Chat.id %}" class="parag delete-btn">Delete chat</a>'+
```

and this is the error :

```
NoReverseMatch at /messages/inbox/
Reverse for 'delete_chat' with keyword arguments '{'id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: 
['messages\\/inbox\\/delete\\/$']
```

can someone plz help me to figure out who to pass the id?

Comment: can show your urls.py code

Comment: as @c.grey said, it's a url problem. You don't have url pointing to this view with these parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL pattern doesn't provide the id. We can see that in the error message: 
`['messages\\/inbox\\/delete\\/$']`.

This url should be:

```py
urlpatterns += [
    path('inbox/delete/<int:id>/', name='delete_chat')
]
```

In addition your `Chat.id` variable is empty: `keyword arguments '{'id': ''}'`, which means either Chat variable doesn't exist or it doesn't have an id attribute or its id attribute is empty. We can't say exactly which, because you show only one line of the template.

Answer (score 0):

correct format:
href="{% url 'msgs:delete_chat' chat.id %}"

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial03/#removing-hardcoded-urls-in-templates

try to call your variables in lowercase*

Comment: There is nothing wrong with his format. He uses the keyword argument form as listed [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

Answer (score 0):

You have no template for the delete chat view so the page has nowhere to redirect. They way you are passing the id is wrong as well. correct format: href="{% url 'msgs:delete_chat' chat.id %}" where chat should be the context of the post defined in the view